# Can I dynamically make c3js graphs?

Tags: javascript, php, loops, c3.js

Here's what I got so far:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
        var names = <?php echo json_encode($array1) ?>;
        var count = <?php echo json_encode($array2) ?>;
        var x=0;
        while (names[x]!=null)
        {
            var chart = c3.generate({
                padding: {
                    top: 0,
                    right: 50,
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 10,
                },
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        ['a1', count[x][0]],
                        ['b2', count[x][1]],
                        ['c3', count[x][2]],
                        ['d4', count[x][3]]
                    ],
                    type: 'pie'
                },

            });
            x=x+1;
        }
        chart.resize({height:200, width:300})
    </script>
```

So I'm right now pulling data from a database, and storing my data in a php array. I then json it to js, and its js name is now called names. 'count' and 'names are both related, so the loop itself is fine. The problem is that I can't figure out how to make many many pie charts as I'm trying to do now. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, but all that is display is one pie chart in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate new DOM elements for avery chart, so in the while you can do:

```js
< script >
  var names = <? php echo json_encode($array1) ?> ;
var count = <? php echo json_encode($array2) ?> ;
var x = 0;
while (names[x] != null) {
  var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  iDiv.id = 'chart' + x;
  document.getElementById('chartsHolder')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto = "#chart" + x;
    padding: {
        top: 0,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 10,
      },
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['a1', count[x][0]],
          ['b2', count[x][1]],
          ['c3', count[x][2]],
          ['d4', count[x][3]]
        ],
        type: 'pie'
      },

  });
  x = x + 1;
}
chart.resize({
  height: 200,
  width: 300
}) < /script>
```

```html
<div id="chartsHolder"></div>
```